# Can't open url from other applications in firefox

Tags: debian, firefox, bspwm

When I try to open an external URL from an application while **Firefox is open** I get this message:

[image: Error Message]

After I close all Firefox instances and try again, Firefox **starts but freezes and continuously loading** with no results like this:

[image: Firefox freezes]

I am using **Bbarebone Debian with `bspwm`**. I really need this features as I am using it in some application to login (unityhub in this example).